# Generate config file using jinja2

Tags: python-3.x

In order to generate configuration file for haproxy for multiple environments, i'm trying to use jinja2 template and configparser. However,  to render the templates, i have to assign the variable of templates to value of the variable that parsed from environment config file:

template.render(var1=myvar1, var2=myvar2...varn=myvarN)

Is possible to have template render using global variable in Python?

Thanks,
Hung Tran